# My word cloud is missing three out of the four words in my string. How do I add the words it's missing?

Tags: python, matplotlib, word-cloud

I am trying to create a word cloud from the sentence, "hi how are you". But I only get the first word. Why?

**Code:**

```
#@title Bar plot of most frequent words.
from wordcloud import WordCloud,STOPWORDS
stopwords = set(STOPWORDS)
wordcloud = WordCloud(
    width=800,height=800,
    stopwords = stopwords,
    min_font_size = 10,
    background_color='white'
).generate("hi how are you") 
# plot the WordCloud image                        
plt.figure(figsize = (8, 8), facecolor = None) 
plt.imshow(wordcloud,interpolation="bilinear") 
plt.axis("off") 
plt.tight_layout(pad = 0) 

plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hi`, `are` and `you` are contained in `STOPWORDS`.

If you want to keep these specific words you need to filter out them from `STOPWORDS`

Like:

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS

stopwords = {word for word in STOPWORDS if word not in {'how', 'are', 'you'}}
wordcloud = WordCloud(
    width=800,height=800,
    stopwords = stopwords,
    min_font_size = 10,
    background_color='white'
).generate("hi how are you")

# plot the WordCloud image           
plt.figure(figsize = (8, 8), facecolor=None)
plt.imshow(wordcloud,interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis("off")
plt.tight_layout(pad = 0)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

In the OP code above, `stopwords` argument is set to the module `STOPWORDS` list. In this list, `how`, `are`, `you` are all included. This restricts these words from showing in the wordcloud.

Note, if this argument is not given, it will also default to this list, so you will need to load in an empty list if you want all words included.